# C# accessing embedded image from within an embedded HTML resource

Tags: c#, resources, webbrowser-control

I want to have two embedded resources in a VS 2013 C# WinForms application.

One is a JPG file: embedding it is very straightforward.

The other is an HTML file (also easy to embed), but it is the contents of the HTML that are giving me fits.  The HTML body needs to reference the embedded JPG file as a resource:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <image src=".... **reference that embedded JPG here**" />
</body>
</html>
```

The goal is to be able to display that HTML file, which consists solely of the image contents, in a WebBrowser control, without needing to store either file independently of the application resources.

I've seen some other answers here referencing WebForms, but none helpful for this task.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Jeff W.

Reading, PA

Comment: A data uri pointing to the base64 representation of the image?

Comment: There is the res:// protocol for resources, not sure if it works for managed resources though.

Comment: Having a single resource thats an MHT? (webpage-single) ?

Comment: Alex, that's an interesting thought re: MHT files.  I'll have to look into that one.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can base-64 encode your image and put it into HTML or CSS. It's not supported on old browsers (pre IE8 I think?) but otherwise you should be good to go. Here's how to do that: https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/

Otherwise, you'll just want to put a placeholder in your stored HTML and swap it out with the base-64 encoded image.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <image src="data:image/gif;base64,{0}" /> <!-- Replace here -->
</body>
</html>
```

C#

```
var html = GetStringResource(); // However you do it.
var imageData = GetImageResource(); // Ditto
var encoded = GetBase64FromBinary(imageData); // TODO
var finalHtml = string.Format(html, encoded);
```

Comment: That is pretty much the same as what Alex posted earlier, except that his method (saving down the file as MHT using IE) automates the encoding.   It turns out that Alex's solution works (since the minimum requirement for the project is IE9), so I consider the matter closed.  Thanks, all!

Comment: @JeffWoods The resource embedded MHT will work in WinXP & Win7, but will not work in Win10 (it will display blank white page). So the best approach is using base64 image within single .html file.